# How to expose two port in webapp for container in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances, azure-webapps, azure-web-app-for-containers

Does web-app for container support exposing multiple ports. Ex my docker image consume two port but in web-app for container, i can only use one port either port 80 or port specified by WEBSITES_PORT in app setting.
[Link to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974255/how-to-expose-web-app-for-container-on-two-different-ports-in-azure) but it been a long time since that so is there currently any way to expose multiple ports on Web-app for container.

Can't use azure container instance (it exposes multiple port) as it does not provide SSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Azure Web App only can expose one port to the outside world and it must be one of port 80 and 443. Take a look at the [limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux#you-can-only-expose-one-port-to-the-outside-worldapplies-to-web-app-for-containers). And you can [Enable a TLS endpoint in a sidecar container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-group-ssl). I think it's more appropriate for you. And both Web App and ACI are not the options as you want. You can try the AKS or directly use the VM.

Comment: another issue while using ACI is that each time container restart, it will assign diffrenet ip address which will break the frontend

Comment: @yatharthmeena Yes, when you restart the container group, actually, it recreates the group with the same configuration. So it will get a new IP address and We cannot decide which IP address it will use.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-application-gateway isn't this the workaround for getting a static ip address

Comment: @yatharthmeena That's not the public IP of the ACI, It belongs to the application gateway.